# Setting values to 2 decimal places in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a very simple question. I need to set my values to 2 decimal places in SQL Server as per below:

```
34.123 --> becomes --> 34.12
34.125 --> becomes --> 34.13
```

In other words if the third decimal is greater or equal to 5, it should add one to the second decimal number.

I have tried round, ceiling but none of these work.

Comment: FLOOR, CEILING and ROUND *do* work. ROUND(34.125) returns exactly what you asked. Trailing zeros *don't* matter in numbers anyway. You can cast to a decimal with 2 decimal digits but that wouldn't affect the outcome at all

Comment: Where do you want to use this result, as if you want to update your value in existing column then first you need to modify the datatype of column to accept just 2 decimal digits. Or if you want to use this result only then you may cast it to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

Just cast to 2 decimal places

```
select cast(34.125 as decimal(10,2))
```